# Sending an email with Sidekiq RSpec Test failed because Array is empty and could not change from 0 to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test sending an email with Sidekiq and I am having an error which means it doesn't enqueue since my test shows it didn't change from 0 to 1 in size. Could it be I am missing something out or how can I fix this?

**Error**

```
expected `Array#size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

  0) Sending Mail sends email to sidekiq
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         OrderPointsMailer.paid_order_email(customer_detail.id).deliver_later
       end.to change(Sidekiq::Worker.jobs, :size).by(1)

       expected `Array#size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/order_points_mailer_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed
```

**binding.pry**

This shows `Sidekiq::Worker.jobs` is `empty array` and it is understandable why it failed but I do not know how I could fix this.

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SendingMailWithSidekiq>)>Sidekiq::Worker.jobs
=> []
```

**app/jobs/order_points_job.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class OrderPointsJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(customer_email)
    customer_detail = CustomerDetail.find_by(email: customer_email)
    return unless customer_detail

    OrderPointsMailer.paid_order_email(customer_detail.id).deliver_later # This call send email to sidekiq process
  end
end
```

**RSpec**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Sending Mail with Sidekiq', type: :request do
  it 'sends email to sidekiq' do
    customer_detail = create(:customer_detail)

    expect do
      OrderPointsMailer.paid_order_email(customer_detail.id).deliver_later
    end.to change(Sidekiq::Worker.jobs, :size).by(1)
  end
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the method `count` instead of `size`:

```
.to change(Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.reload, :count).by(1)
```

Take a look at the `size` implementation:

```
From: /home/toptal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb @ line 260:
Owner: ActiveRecord::Relation
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count(:all)
end
```

Also take a look on the matcher implementation (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/change.rb#L82:L85)

I'm guessing that the receiver (`Sidekiq::Worker.jobs` in your case) will be evaluated once, and then the `size` would be called twice on the same objects collection, without reloading.

One other approach you could take would be

```
.to change { Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.reload.size }.by(1)
```

But this would be a bit wasteful in case you have more records in the DB, because each time the AR objects will need to be created (and they're not used)

Comment: I agree with the `.size` and `.count` methods. But won't this give me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'reload' for []:Array`? Let me try. I will give you feedback.

Comment: Yes it returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'reload' for []:Array`. The array is just empty. I don't know what I can do from here

Comment: But does the fist solution work for you (count instead of size)? To be honest i prefer `change{}` instead of `change(x, y)` and I don't use the second approach myself. I updated my answer to `.to change { Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.reload.size }.by(1)`

Comment: And `reload` will be a problem too here. `NoMethodError: undefined method 'reload' for []:Array`. Array or the Number#Size is just empty