# RSpec mailer test with Sidekiq sends error with empty []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I'm trying to test sending an email with Sidekiq. Locally it works well but I don't know why I'm getting below error:

```
  1) UserMailer#welcome_email when user is newly registered send email to sidekiq
     Failure/Error:
       expect{
         UserMailer.welcome_email(account.id).deliver_later
       }.to change{ Sidekiq::Worker.jobs }.by(1)

       expected `Sidekiq::Worker.jobs` to have changed by 1, but was changed by []
```

I came across the same error in this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059988/sending-an-email-with-sidekiq-rspec-test-failed-because-array-is-empty-and-could) but without but the solution proposed does not work.

spec:

```
RSpec.describe UserMailer, type: :mailer do
  describe '#welcome_email' do
    let(:account) { create(:account) }

    context 'when user is newly registered' do
      it 'send email to sidekiq' do
        expect{
          UserMailer.with(account: account).welcome_email.deliver_later
        }.to change{ Sidekiq::Worker.jobs }.by(1)
      end
```

It's Grape API, here is the place where email is sent:

```
    post :create do
      @account = Account.create!(declared(params))
      UserMailer.with(account: @account).welcome_email.deliver_later if @account.save
      AccountSerializer.new(@account)
    end
```

and I am having an error which means it doesn't enqueue since my test shows it didn't change from 0 to 1 in size.

Comment: You can try testing the number of jobs change, not just `jobs` - `Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.size`

Comment: Ok now I'm getting `expected Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.size to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: Might be because of `deliver_later`? What about `deliver_now`?

Comment: Nope, the same error `jobs.size to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: Try reloading, `Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.reload.size`.

Comment: I'm getting an error `NoMethodError: undefined method `reload' for []:Array`

Comment: Does `UserMailer.with(account: account).welcome_email.deliver_later` enqueue a job by itself? How's defined?

Comment: I think Sidekiq has this as default, the only thing what I've got, except standard config for Sidekiq is sidekiq.yml: ---
:concurrency: 10
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers

Comment: So instead of using `change {}` try using [`have_enqueued_job`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher).

Comment: Why are testing that Sidekiq works? Hasn't the Sidekiq team already written a test that proves that `deliver_later` works. You should limit your testing to your own code. You should only be testing that you made the proper call. (I can show you how in an answer if you want.)

Comment: @aridlehoover good point, it's like testing Devise... nevertheless could you please show me this call test?